# DJANGO not receiving data with POST

Tags: django, fetch

I'm having an issue trying to send data with fetch to DJANGO.

I want to send some data to django through fetch but when I debug I receive nothing in the post value, do you know what could be happening?

This is my fetch call:

```
const defaults = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'credentials': 'include',
    'headers': new Headers({
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }),
    data:{'name':'A name'},
    dataType:'json'
}

const response = await fetch (url, defaults)
```

When I debug I get an empty querydict in the request.POST

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you use the request.POST. what parameters have you given it

Comment: request.POST['name'] but there's nothing in the request.POST variable so it's useless. I check the data with the debugger I still haven't wrote the code to receive it

Comment: It seems like it doesn't recognices the name. You might have to loop through the "defaults" objects to get that.

Comment: Try request.POST.get('name')

Comment: Try also request.POST.get(["defaults"][3])

Comment: Nope, not working, I think the problem is that django is not receiving the data object

Comment: Are you sure that this is Django question?

Comment: are you using a frontend library like reactJS

Comment: Yeah it is a Django question, I'm using Django for this. It's just a javascript-django quesiton.